# Disable Option 2 when Option 1 is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to adapt some code I've used for a website I'm creating for a school I work for, to disallow certain options to be selected at the same time.

The user is presented the following HTML drop down list 6 times:

```
<select type="select" name="optRes2" select id="optRes2">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...</option>
    <option value="Art">Art</option>
    <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
    <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
    <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Food Technology">Food Technology</option>
    <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
    <option value="German">German</option>
    <option value="History">History</option>
    <option value="Music">Music</option>
    <option value="Philosophy and Ethics">Philosophy and Ethics</option>
    <option value="Product Design">Product Design</option>
    <option value="Physical Education">Physical Education</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
    <option value="Science (Triple)">Science (Triple Award - 3 GCSEs)</option>
    <option value="Textiles">Textiles</option>
</select>
```

The user should NOT be able to select both Art and Textiles at the same time. They can select EITHER Art OR Textiles - but not both.

For example: User selects 'Art' in opt1, so Textiles is disabled in the remaining 5 menus. If the user goes back and deselects Art, Textiles should then be enabled throughout. Hopefully you understand what I mean.

I already have the code to prevent the same option being selected multiple times:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'opt1' && $(this).val() == 'Default'){
            $('select').not(this).prop('disabled', true).val('Disabled');
        } else {
            $('select').not(this).removeProp('disabled');
            $('select option').removeProp('disabled');
            $('select').each(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if(val != 'Default' || val != 'Disabled'){
                    $('select option[value="'+val+'"]').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The user then clicks submit and all of this is then submit to a MySQL server for review at a later date.

Menus are named opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, optRes1 and optRes2.

Thanks everyone,

Jack

Comment: Maybe something like `<option value="Art" data-not-with="Textiles">` (and the reverse for Textiles), then check that attribute within your change handler to see which (if any) other options to disable. As an aside, why not art and textiles at the same time? They're quite different subjects...

Comment: why not user `onchange` event and than array.`filter` opeartion?

Comment: @nnnnnn, its basically a GCSE thing, and the school have requested that the users cannot take both courses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a data attribute named `notallowed`. There you can set which value that should be disabled. And when a value is changed we also check if we previously disabled some fields and re-enable them.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
    
    var notAllowed = $(this).find('option:selected').data('notallowed');
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    // Get the previous selected value.
    var oldValue = $(this).data('old');
    
    // Keep track of the previous selected value.
    $(this).data('old', currentValue);
    
    // Re-enabled all that was disabled by the previous selection.
    if(oldValue) {
      // Re-enable the old value in the other selects.
      $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + oldValue +'"]').prop('disabled', false);
      
      // Get the option.
      var previousNotAllowed = $(this).find('option[value="' + oldValue +'"]').data('notallowed');
      if(previousNotAllowed){
        $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + previousNotAllowed +'"]').prop('disabled', false);
      }
    }
    
  // If we selected a option with notallowed attribute we should disable that option in the other selects.
    if(notAllowed){
      var items = $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + notAllowed +'"]').prop('disabled',true);
    }
  
  // Disable the current value in other selects.  
  $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + currentValue +'"]').prop('disabled', true);
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type="select" name="optRes1" select id="optRes1">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...</option>
  <option value="Art" data-notallowed="Textiles">Art</option>
  <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
  <option value="Computing" data-notallowed="Drama">Computing</option>
  <option value="Drama" data-notallowed="Computing">Drama</option>
  <option value="French">French</option>
  <option value="Food Technology">Food Technology</option>
  <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
  <option value="German">German</option>
  <option value="History">History</option>
  <option value="Music">Music</option>
  <option value="Philosophy and Ethics">Philosophy and Ethics</option>
  <option value="Product Design">Product Design</option>
  <option value="Physical Education">Physical Education</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science (Triple)">Science (Triple Award - 3 GCSEs)</option>
  <option value="Textiles" data-notallowed="Art">Textiles</option>
</select>
 
<select type="select" name="optRes2" select id="optRes2">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...</option>
  <option value="Art" data-notallowed="Textiles">Art</option>
  <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
  <option value="Computing" data-notallowed="Drama">Computing</option>
  <option value="Drama" data-notallowed="Computing">Drama</option>
  <option value="French">French</option>
  <option value="Food Technology">Food Technology</option>
  <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
  <option value="German">German</option>
  <option value="History">History</option>
  <option value="Music">Music</option>
  <option value="Philosophy and Ethics">Philosophy and Ethics</option>
  <option value="Product Design">Product Design</option>
  <option value="Physical Education">Physical Education</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science (Triple)">Science (Triple Award - 3 GCSEs)</option>
  <option value="Textiles" data-notallowed="Art">Textiles</option>
</select>
<select type="select" name="optRes3" select id="optRes3">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...</option>
  <option value="Art" data-notallowed="Textiles">Art</option>
  <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
  <option value="Computing" data-notallowed="Drama">Computing</option>
  <option value="Drama" data-notallowed="Computing">Drama</option>
  <option value="French">French</option>
  <option value="Food Technology">Food Technology</option>
  <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
  <option value="German">German</option>
  <option value="History">History</option>
  <option value="Music">Music</option>
  <option value="Philosophy and Ethics">Philosophy and Ethics</option>
  <option value="Product Design">Product Design</option>
  <option value="Physical Education">Physical Education</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science (Triple)">Science (Triple Award - 3 GCSEs)</option>
  <option value="Textiles" data-notallowed="Art">Textiles</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ahahahahaha, 3 html selects instead of data filter operations

Comment: @degr - The OP said _The user is presented the following HTML drop down list 6 times_. So I assumed it actually shows the same select 6 times. However, I only included it 3 times.

Comment: @degr - Also, based on the code the OP provided it seems as all the selects are showed at the same time: `$('select').not(this)` and _Menus are named opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, optRes1 and optRes2._

Comment: @JackAnyon - Yes. It is enabled in the same dropdown, but not the others. I thought that was the expected behavior?

Comment: Okay so this did work, but I had to change your `<option value="Textiles" data-notallowed="Textiles">Textiles</option>` to `<option value="Textiles" data-notallowed="Textiles">Art</option>` on the last line. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a overlapping div with id selection and then select every select and disable the chosen option on change like so:

```
<div id="selection">
            <select type="select" name="optRes2" select id="optRes2">
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...                       </option>
                <option value="Art">Art</option>
                 etc
            </select>
    <select type="select" name="optRes3" select id="optRes3">
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...                       </option>
                <option value="Art">Art</option>
                 etc
            </select>
    </div>
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
    $( "#optRes2" ).change(function() {
      $("div#selection select.select option").each(function(){
             if($(this).val()== $('#optRes2').val() ){ 
                $(this).attr("disabled","true");    
             }
       });
    });
    $( "#optRes3" ).change(function() {
      $("div#selection select.select option").each(function(){
             if($(this).val()== $('#optRes3').val() ){ 
                $(this).attr("disabled","true");    
             }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better create options array, and work with data, not with HTML. Using this approach you will be able to stay DRY.

Think solution is clear.

```
<html>
<body>

<select type="select" name="optRes3" select id="optRes1">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...</option>
  <option value="Art">Art</option>
  <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
  <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
  <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
  <option value="French">French</option>
  <option value="Food Technology">Food Technology</option>
  <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
  <option value="German">German</option>
  <option value="History">History</option>
  <option value="Music">Music</option>
  <option value="Philosophy and Ethics">Philosophy and Ethics</option>
  <option value="Product Design">Product Design</option>
  <option value="Physical Education">Physical Education</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science (Triple)">Science (Triple Award - 3 GCSEs)</option>
  <option value="Textiles">Textiles</option>
</select>
<select type="select" name="optRes3" select id="optRes2">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...</option>
  <option value="Art">Art</option>
  <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
  <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
  <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
  <option value="French">French</option>
  <option value="Food Technology">Food Technology</option>
  <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
  <option value="German">German</option>
  <option value="History">History</option>
  <option value="Music">Music</option>
  <option value="Philosophy and Ethics">Philosophy and Ethics</option>
  <option value="Product Design">Product Design</option>
  <option value="Physical Education">Physical Education</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science (Triple)">Science (Triple Award - 3 GCSEs)</option>
  <option value="Textiles">Textiles</option>
</select>
<select type="select" name="optRes3" select id="optRes3">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select an option...</option>
  <option value="Art">Art</option>
  <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
  <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
  <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
  <option value="French">French</option>
  <option value="Food Technology">Food Technology</option>
  <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
  <option value="German">German</option>
  <option value="History">History</option>
  <option value="Music">Music</option>
  <option value="Philosophy and Ethics">Philosophy and Ethics</option>
  <option value="Product Design">Product Design</option>
  <option value="Physical Education">Physical Education</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science (Triple)">Science (Triple Award - 3 GCSEs)</option>
  <option value="Textiles">Textiles</option>
</select>

<script>
function OptResDropdown(htmlDropdown, value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.dropdown = htmlDropdown;
    this.options = this.initOptions(htmlDropdown.options);
    var selected = htmlDropdown.options[htmlDropdown.selectedIndex];
    this.value = value? value : (selected ? selected.value : 0); 
    var me = this;
    htmlDropdown.addEventListener('change', function(event){
        me.value = event.target.value;
        me.update(me.value);
    });
    this.update();
}

OptResDropdown.instances = {};

OptResDropdown.prototype.initOptions = function(options){
    var me = this;
    var out = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var option = options[i];
        out.push({value: option.value, label: option.innerText});
    }
    return out;
};

OptResDropdown.prototype.update = function(value) {
    for(var key in OptResDropdown.instances) {
        var me = OptResDropdown.instances[key];
        me.dropdown.innerHTML = '';
        var options;
        if(value === 'Art') {
            options = me.options.filter(function(option){
                return option.value !== 'Textiles';
            });
        } else if(value === 'Textiles') {
            options = me.options.filter(function(option){
                return option.value !== 'Art';
            });
        } else {
            options = me.options;
        }
        options.forEach(function(option){
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = option.value;
            opt.innerText = option.label;
            me.dropdown.appendChild(opt);
        })
        me.dropdown.value = me.value;
    }
};



var opt1 = new OptResDropdown(optRes1);
var opt2 = new OptResDropdown(optRes2);
var opt3 = new OptResDropdown(optRes3);

OptResDropdown.instances.opt1 = opt1;
OptResDropdown.instances.opt2 = opt2;
OptResDropdown.instances.opt3 = opt3;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```